# Finding Linear programming optimal solution.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, simplex-method

*Consider the following linear program:*

*max* $z = 4x_1+x_2+5x_3+3x_4$

*subject to*
$x_1-x_2-x_3+3x_4 \le 1$

$5x_1+x_2+3x_3+8x_4\le55$

$-x_1+2x_2+3x_3-5x_4\le3$

*It is claimed that the solution $x^*=(0, 14, 0, 5)$ is an optimal solution to the problem. Give a proof of the claim.*

I have to proof the problem **without using the simplex method** to solve this problem.
How can it be possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the theorem that every optimal solution of a linear program is in an edge (provided the set of solutions is not empty and bounded)?

Comment: It is not commented. Maybe it can be possible.

Comment: Possible hint: the dual.

Comment: you mean dual simplex method?

Comment: For showing that the set of solutions is bounded you could use that the dual problem has a solution. By this I mean the transformation of the linear program to the dual linear program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objectiva value is $29$. Hence if we can exhibit a feasible solution with the same objective value in the dual problem then we are done.

Let's write down the dual:

$$\min p_1+55p_2+3p_3$$

subject to

$$p_1 + 5p_2-p_3 = 4 $$ 
$$-p_1+p_2+2p_3=1$$

$$-p_1+3p_2+3p_3=5$$

$$3p_1+8p_2-5p_3=3$$

$$p \ge 0$$

Also, from complementary slackness condition we know that $p_2=0$.

We can easily check that the linear system has no feasible solution. Hence the claimed solution can't be optimal.

---

View the original problem as

$$\max c^Tx$$

subject to $$Ax \le b$$

$A$ is of full row rank and the nullity is $1$, that is there is this vector $d \ne 0$ such that $Ad=0$.

If we compute $c^Td\ne 0$, then we have found a direction that can increase the objective value indefinitely.

Comment: @hwan: to see that this solves the problem you have to be aware of the property, that for the primal problem *max* $c^Tx$ and the dual problem *min* $y^Tp$, $$ c^Tx\leq y^Tp$$ holds. So if they are equal, you can't maximize $c^Tx$ anymore, i.e. if you found a $p$ with  $y^Tp=29$ this is you upper boundary for $c^Tx$ .

Comment: One thing that I was curious is why the dual problem has equality? not inequality

Comment: the constraint in the dual comes from the variable in primal. it it equality because the primal has no sign constraint.

Comment: I must study about the dual problem and sign constraint. Can you recommend one ?

Comment: [here](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-04.pdf) you go. Table $4.1$ gives the rule.

Comment: Thank you very much